# Splitting and renaming a file using a word delimiter in Linux

Tags: linux, unix, awk, command-line

I have a file as follows

File name split.txt

```
file part alpha
abc
def
hij
file part beta
klm
nop
file part charlie
qrs
tuv
wxy
zzz
```

The file needs to be delimited on the "file part" line and renamed according to last word in the file part line. i.e. after the split, I should have three files as follows:

File 1 - file name is alpha.txt

```
abc
def
hij
```

File 2 - file name is beta.txt

```
klm
nop
```

File 3 - file name is charlie.txt

```
qrs
tuv
wxy
zzz
```

Thus far, I have managed to split the file using the following command

```
awk '/file part/{n++}{print >"file" n ".txt"}' split.txt
```

This results in the file names being file1.txt, file2.txt and file3.txt.

How do I get the file names to be alpha.txt, beta.txt and charlie.txt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one-liner should help:

```
awk '/file part/{fn=$NF ".txt"}{print > fn}' split.txt
```

The idea is same as your codes, just change the sequence number by the last word in the line as filename.

Comment: You should mention that unless that's GNU awk the OP will probably need a `close(fn)` immediately before the `fn=...` to avoid a "too many open files" error.

Comment: @EdMorton , thanks.. I knew the `close()` and `too many open files` trick, but it won't happen with gawk? or it is implemented in new version? I haven't read the latest release note.

Comment: You're welcome. gawk has internally managed the number of open files for as along as I've been using it, so several years/releases. It's just one of these things that without gawk will work for a small sample input file and then blow up later so it's worth explicitly stating in every answer.